# replace/remove awk/sed/vim column elements after a character

Tags: text, vim, awk, sed, replace

I have a text file which contains single column entries,

```
1745:1745
1746:1746
1747:1747
1748:1748
42:42
43:43
44:44
45:45
46:46
```

And I want to remove the duplication of numbers, i.e. remove all the characters starting with (including) colon, with the output format,

```
1745
1746
1747
1748
42
43
44
45
46
```

How can I do it ?

Thanks

Comment: `man cut`: `-d use DELIM instead of TAB for field delimiter` and `-f select only these fields`

Answer (score 3):

```
cut -d ':' -f 1 < file.txt
```

This seems to work, huh ?

Comment: Yes, you don't need `<` though. It works, if you don't have lines like `1:2:3`.

Answer (score 3):

For given input below `awk` should work

```
awk -F':' '{ print $1 }' infile
```

Comment: Or even `$0 = $1`

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following, these ones based on substitution from colon to till end with null.

***Solution 1st:*** Using `awk`:

```
awk '{sub(/:.*/,"")} 1'  Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:*** Using `sed`:

```
sed 's/:.*//g'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

Using vim, a find/replace would do

```
%s/:.*
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding below command which will check and print only the values which has duplicated entry in both the columns:

`awk -F":" '{if ($1 == $2) print $1 }' input_file`